# sax builder not parsing correctly

Tags: java, parsing, xsd, schema, saxparser

I am trying to parse an xml file for reviewing and editing, but when i use the sax builder to parse the xml file it returns an object that is missing some attributes. Just to be sure that it is not something i have caused while the program is traversing and editing the xml file, i have open, parsed, and then save the file and it still seems to be missing attributes. I am writing this code in java, using intellij. To remedy the problem i have to tried to insert a schema to help the parser parse correctly, but then i get the error :

```
Error on line 2 of document file:/C:/Documents/XMLguide/Tv_201503090900%20-%20Orig%20-%20Copy.xml: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'foo'
```

My XML File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo xmlns:mpeg7="urn:tva:mpeg7:2008" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xml:lang="EN" publisher="fooBar" publicationTime="0B.C." version="1" xmlns="urn:tva:metadata:2010">........
```

My Parsing Code:

```
    //create file path from xmlPath argument
    Path filePath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(xmlPath);
    File XMLfile = filePath.toFile();
    File schemaFile = new File("XMLSchema.xsd");
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

    //new document
    document = new Document();

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

    //try to read and parse xml with saxBuilder
    try {
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
        factory.setSchema(schema);

        XMLReaderJDOMFactory xmlFactory = new XMLReaderSchemaFactory(schema);
        SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder(xmlFactory);
        document = saxBuilder.build(XMLfile);
```

`XMLSchema.xsd` is the schema file I downloaded from `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Im not really sure how to answer this question, but this is the link to the schema file: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, i am very new to XML and Parsing it

Comment: Im starting to think that i need to change my career plans here

Comment: `new File("XMLSchema.xsd")` looks like a local file. So you downloaded that xsd and used it, instead of a custom one? Is that correct?

Comment: i am trying to find a free/open source schema generator but i am not having much luck. The only free ones i see are ones that are browser based and i can not post this information on the web

Comment: The [eclipse Model Development Tools](https://eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=xsd) contain a visual xsd editor, but you still need to know the basics (http://www.w3schools.com/schema/). Alternatively you could create java classes matching your xml structure, annotate them with the correct annotations and use jaxb schemagen to generate your xsd file for you (but personally I like do it the other way round, i.e. create the xsd file(s) and let jaxb create the classes). But learning how to use those annotations could be just as difficult as learning xsd. BTW you need to use a custom xsd.

Comment: Thank you i am going to take some time and go over the w3schools turtorial.

Comment: Hello, i am back. I have found a way to generate a custom xsd for my xml file using trang. but after doing that i am now getting the error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/jwright2/Documents/intelliJ/XMLguideUpdate/xsi.xsd; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 47; no-xsi: The {target namespace} of an attribute declaration must not match 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'.